# How to import csv with complex fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have the following line in a csv file

```
"\"xyz\"; blabla";"u98r34u98r3"
```

This is supposed to contain two fields:

`"\"xyz\"; blabla"` and `"u98r34u98r3"`

I'm trying to import it with `pandas.read_csv()` on python 3.4.3 but it only gives three fields:

`xyz"`, `blabla"` and `u98r34u98r3`

I tried my luck with options `escapechar=`, `quotechar=` and `doublequote=` without success.

//edit:

The problem was, that I extracted the specific piece and tried to parse it as string like this:

```
from io import StringIO  
import pandas as pd  
data = u'"\"xyz\"; blabla";"u98r34u98r3"'  
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=";", escapechar="\\")
```

But it worked when parsing the complete file.

Comment: Can you post what you tried and what the results were?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me using `sep=";"` and `escapechar="\\"` in pandas 0.19.2:

```
In [27]: df = pd.read_csv("quote.csv", header=None, sep=";",  escapechar="\\")

In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
               0            1
0  "xyz"; blabla  u98r34u98r3

In [29]: df.values
Out[29]: array([['"xyz"; blabla', 'u98r34u98r3']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was, that I extracted the specific piece ind tried to parse it as string like this:  

   ` from io import StringIO  
    import pandas as pd  
    data = u'"\"xyz\"; blabla";"u98r34u98r3"'  
    pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=";") `  


But it worked when parsing the complete file.